# Why won't javascript replace innerHTML on screen resolution check?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make my website check the screen resolution and replace installed font icons (using @webfont) with plain text links, so that the site is more mobile friendly.  Im using Opera Mobile Emulator to check if it works.  the user interface I am using clearly comes back with a res of 480x320 (in the very top left of the page), yet the .innerHTML javascript isn't firing off.  Any help?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<title>Harry's Bar</title>

    <meta name="keywords" content="Harry's, bar, st. petersburg, florida, kenneth city, drink specials" />

    <meta name="description" content="Harry's Bar in St. Petersburg, Florida.  Drink specials every night!" />

    <meta name="author" content="Internet Solutions of Florida" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" /> 
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var width=screen.width;
var height=screen.height;
document.write(width+'x'+height);
if (width<700)
    {document.getElementById("homelink").innerHTML="Home";}

</script>

<div class="frame">
<div class="header">
<img class="logo" src="img/logo.png" alt="Harry's Bar" />
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
        <li><a id="homelink" href="index.html" title="home">&#xf015</a></li>
        <li><a id="drinklink" href="drinks.html" title="drink menu">&#xf0fc</a></li>
        <li><a id="piclink" href="images.html" title="picture gallery">&#xf030</a></li>
        <li><a id="directionslink" href="directions.html" title="directions">&#xf0d1</a></li>
        <li><a id="contactlink" href="contact.html" title="contact us">&#xf075</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That javascript is executing before the HTML is being loaded. So there is no element with the id of "homelink" when the javascript fires.

Additionally, by using document.write, you're effectively overwriting your original HTML, so the tag will never load anyway.

Get rid of the document.write call and place the script just before your closing body tag and it should work as intended.

Comment: Aha.  I just started with js about a week ago so Im still fuzzy about placement and hierarchy.  Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

1. document.write() is not needed. If you want to diagnose you may use document.title or create a div and divid.innerHTML
2. Make sure your testing on a <700 area
3. Add a DOM ready fire.
4. Place this at the end of the

Things should work then :)